# Как проверить нажата ли кнопка в другом активити после ее закрытия

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity

я новичок в програмировании, так вот, у меня есть MediaPlayer, мне нужно из активити настроек управлять его звуком, т.е я создал Activity_setting а там 4 кнопки, каждой кнопки присвоил код, чтобы результат возвращался в другое активити, код выглядит так:

```
Intent intent20 = new Intent(setting_activity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent20.putExtra("Sound20", 0.2f);
startActivity(intent20);
```

В MainActivity собственно получаю кнопку

```
final float sound20 = getIntent().getFloatExtra("Sound20", 0.2f);
```

И делаю так

```
myMediaPlayer.setVolume(sound20, sound20);
```

Вроде, все работает.
Но у меня помимо одной кнопки регулировки звука в settings_activty есть целых 4, так вот, как дать понять из MainActivity была нажата кнопка btnSound20 и создать условие или switch который будет проверять на какую кнопку нажали, а там уже можно и звук изменить....

Формулировать мысль хорошо не получается, но, для тех кто не понял:
У меня будет

```
final float sound20 = getIntent().getFloatExtra("Sound20", 0.2f
final float sound40 = getIntent().getFloatExtra("Sound20", 0.4f);
final float sound60 = getIntent().getFloatExtra("Sound20", 0.6f);
final float sound80 = getIntent().getFloatExtra("Sound20", 0.8f);
final float sound100 = getIntent().getFloatExtra("Sound20", 1.0f);
```

Я имею виду, что сделать чтобы программа поняла какую кнопку я нажал в settings_activity и после этого сделать условие типа: Если нажата btnSound20 то myMediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.setVolume(sound20, sound20). и так далее...
Заранее благодарен..

Comment: если я Вас правильно понял,  то можно передавать для каждой кнопки свой intentKey

Comment: можно по подробнее?

Comment: 4 кнопки - это 4 уровня громкости что ли?

Comment: да, конечно....

Comment: @k1ceargy у Вас есть ключ "Sound20", можно сделать такие же ключи для остальных кнопок: "Sound40", "Sound60"... И проверять если есть какое-то значение, то нажата соответствующая кнопка

Comment: А как проверить, if (sound20) не катит.

Comment: можно передавать дефолтное значение "-1" и проверять по значению

Comment: почему через if не катит ?

Comment: А как передать то? return?

Comment: через if (sound20) компилятор подчеркивает красным, и написано несовместимые переменные Float - Boolean

Comment: сравнивайте с дефолтным значением, например, if (sound20 != -1)

Comment: Сейчас попробую, а -1 это обязательно, или на ее месте может быть любое отрицательное число?

Comment: может быть вообще любое число, отличное от того которое Вам нужно

Comment: Так, я попробовал с первым значением Sound20 и вроде работает, сделал то же условие if (sound40 != -1) и что то не помогает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего не нужно, используйте один ключ и по нему получайте значение

```
    final float sound = getIntent().getFloatExtra("Sound20", 0.2f);
```

его и используйте  без всяких условий

```
    myMediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.setVolume(sound, sound);
```

Значение переменной `sound` будет разным, в зависимости от нажатой кнопки (Вы ведь под каждой кнопкой разное значение передали).

Comment: А переделывать значение можно ? если да, это очень круто

Comment: В каком смысле переделывать? Этот код будет выполняться при каждом возвращении из `Activity_setting`, а следовательно и каждый раз будет получено новое значение в переменную `sound`.

Comment: Я делаю так: в settings_activity intent20.putExtra("Sound20", 0.2f); каждом обрабочике ставлю этот, и не получается ничего.

Comment: Ключ (`"Sound20"`) один, а значение (`0.2f, 0.4f` и т.д.) у каждой кнопки своё.

Comment: так предполагал, сейчас попробуем.